# Write back to scope after modifying with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a table. Every row has a sorting value from the database:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Behandler</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Ort</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Reihenfolge</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="behand in behandler | orderBy: 'sort'">
      <td ng-hide="editActive">{{behand.name}}</td>
      <td ng-hide="editActive">{{behand.ort}}</td>
      <td class="index">{{behand.sort}}</td>
      <td class="id" style="display:none">{{behand.id}}</td>
      <td><a class="edit-button" ng-click="editBehandler(behand.id, behand.name, behand.ort, behand.sort)">Bearbeiten</a> &#124; <a class="delete-button" ng-click="deleteBehandler({{behand.id}})">Löschen</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The user is able to sort this table:

```
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
      var $originals = tr.children();
      var $helper = tr.clone();
      $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
      });
      return $helper;
    },
    updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
      $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
        $(this).html(i + 1);
        // update the scope with the updated sorting values
      });
    };

    $(".table tbody").sortable({
      helper: fixHelperModified,
      stop: updateIndex
    }).disableSelection();
```

The table is updating nice. The new sorting values are getting inserted to the correct cells. But the values inserted by jQuerys .html() function is not reflected to the scope, so that I can save that to my database.

How to insert the shown sorting values to the scope?

Comment: jQuery doesn't provide the two way data binding that handlebars does... So I presume you are losing that binding when updating DOM using jQuery. Is it essential to use jQuery in this cirmunstance? jQuery and Angular is generally a no no... Perhaps take a look at this? http://ui-grid.info/

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things I would just use the $index property of the ng-repeat and remove the stop listener code behind completely:

```
<tr ng-repeat="behand in behandler | orderBy: 'sort'">
  <td ng-hide="editActive">{{behand.name}}</td>
  <td ng-hide="editActive">{{behand.ort}}</td>
  <td class="index">{{$index + 1}}</td>
  <td class="id" style="display:none">{{behand.id}}</td>
  <td><a class="edit-button" ng-click="editBehandler(behand.id, behand.name, behand.ort, $index + 1)">Bearbeiten</a> &#124; <a class="delete-button" ng-click="deleteBehandler({{behand.id}})">Löschen</a></td>
</tr>
```